# sql adding from the same INNER JOIN multiple options from same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Basically I want to select and INNER JOIN 2 tables only but on the second INNER JOIN I want to add the attributes which ON checks that they are joined I want to add 3 values to that JOIN. Basically INNER JOIN same table twice Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
INNER JOIN user_cat ON user_cat.cat_one = categories.category 
   AND user_cat.cat_two = categories.category 
   AND user_cat.cat_three = categories.category
```

Basically the above code does not work. When I tried selecting both of the tables and checking if the code would work that did not work neither. Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM categories, user_cat 
WHERE user_cat.cat_one = categories.category 
   AND user_cat.cat_two = categories.category 
   AND user_cat.cat_three = categories.category
```

How can I change my select to allow the check of all tree columns?

Comment: can you post your sample data?

Comment: student gamer entertainer

Comment: The join's `ON` clause is row by row, so it cannot be equal to all 3 of those values. Perhaps you mean `OR`? Please edit your question above to post a sample of actual rows from these two tables, and a sample of what output rowset you expect your query to produce.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like.....

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_cat UC
LEFT JOIN  categories C1 ON UC.cat_one   = C1.category
LEFT JOIN  categories C2 ON UC.cat_two   = C2.category 
LEFT JOIN  categories C3 ON UC.cat_three = C3.category
```

Comment: Naw the other way around FROM user_cat but FROM categories....tried that one and nothing....